# What is the replacement for XCTAssertEqualObjects?

Tags: ios, swift, xctest

Not sure exactly when but at least as of Xcode 7.2, `XCTAssertEqualObjects` is no longer available.

Is there a replacement for this without having to resort to?

```
   XCTAssertTrue(foo == bar)
```

Note that Apple's ["Writing Test Classes and Methods"](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/testing_with_xcode/chapters/04-writing_tests.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014132-CH4-SW19) appears out of date and still refers to the missing class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would be a bit more specific about what you are testing.

Equality and identity are not the same thing, especially in Swift where there are far richer value types.

If you want to test equality as defined by conformance to `Equatable` then use:

```
XCTAssertTrue(a == b)
```

If you want to test that two reference types are equal:

```
XCTAssertTrue(a === b)
```

I feel this is better because the assertion is more explicit; are the objects equal or identical.

Remember the WWDC15 session on Value Types in Swift - which recommends always making your value types conform to `Equatable`.

Answer (score 4):

For Swift you can just use `XCTAssertEqual`.

Your objects need to implement the `Equatable` protocol so the macro can use `==`.

---

Example:

```
import XCTest

class A: Equatable {
    let name: String
    init(name: String) {
        self.name = name
    }
}
func ==(lhs: A, rhs: A) -> Bool {
    return lhs.name == rhs.name
}

class FooTests: XCTestCase {
    func testFoo() {
        let a = A(name: "foo")
        let a1 = A(name: "foo")
        let b = A(name: "bar")
        XCTAssertEqual(a, a)
        XCTAssertEqual(a, a1)
        XCTAssertEqual(a, b)    // will fail
    }
}
```

Comment: doesn't work unfortunately. See my comment on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25341705/xctassertequal-for-custom-objects-in-swift XCTAssertEqual does not trigger the breakpoint in my custom implementation of ==. XCTAssertEqual appears to return based upon object equivalence. To trigger my == func I have to specify XCTAssertTrue(a == b)

Comment: @MaxMacLeod `XCTAssertEquals` does make use  of the equality operator. Perhaps the problem lies somewhere else in your code.

Comment: @MaxMacLeod I've added an example, setting a breakpoint in the `==` func stops execution three times.

Comment: @MaxMacLeod: If the class inherits from NSObject then you probably have to override `isEqual:` instead of `==`. Compare http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33319959/nsobject-subclass-in-swift-hash-vs-hashvalue-isequal-vs.

Comment: @Cristik yes I do subclass NSObject so it's already implementing Equatable. That could be the issue. I'll give Martin R's suggestion a try.